# How to read JBoss system properties in Perl Script?

Tags: perl, jboss7.x

I want to read JBoss System Properties values in Perl Script. 
I have tried the way how we can read the Environment variables in Perl 
but which is not working correctly.

Mentioned below code snippet what i have tried :

```
my $jboss_home = $ENV{'jboss.home.dir'};
print "JBoss home is $jboss_home"
```

***Is there any alternative way to read system properties in perl script?***

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. The output is .home.dir

Answer (score 0):

The shell variables can't contains any dot `.`

I think there's a mistake on the variable name.

Instead, try :

```
my $jboss_home = $ENV{'JBOSS_HOME'};
print "JBoss home is $jboss_home"
```

Comment: Also, take a look at the [Env](http://perldoc.perl.org/Env.html) module in Perl. It puts all imported variables in a single location, and can limit what gets imported.